# about independent identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$ be independent random variables which has the same distribution, m is natural number.

Is following equality true:

$$P(\bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty}X_1 \in[\frac{1}{k},\infty))=P(\bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty}X_k \in[\frac{1}{k},\infty))$$

In one hand I feel like it should be true because of the same distribution, in other hand the following is true:

$$P(\bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty}X_k \in[\frac{1}{k},\infty))=\prod_{k=m}^{\infty}P(X_k \in [\frac{1}{k},\infty))=\prod_{k=m}^{\infty}P(X_1 \in [\frac{1}{k},\infty))$$

So we get:

$$P(\bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty}X_1 \in[\frac{1}{k},\infty))=\prod_{k=m}^{\infty}P(X_1 \in [\frac{1}{k},\infty))$$

Which I think is not true since events $X_1 \in [\frac{1}{k},\infty)$ are not independent for different $k$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What does it mean to take an infinite intersection of a single random variable?  Do you mean that we should take infinitely many independent trials of that variable?  But then, that is exactly what the $X_k$ are.

Comment: $P(\bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty}X_1 \in[\frac{1}{k},\infty))$ means probability that $X_1$ lies in $[\frac{1}{k},\infty)$ for all $k$ greater or equal to $m$

Comment: So...it's just the probability that $X_1≥\frac 1m$?  Why would you think that this was the same as requiring that infinitely many trials be in some prescribed range?

Comment: yeah I see I overcomplicated it, yes to your first sentence, I dont understand your second sentence, why infinitely many? $X_1 \geq \frac{1}{m}$ is $X_1(w) \geq \frac{1}{m}$, one trial: $w$.

Comment: Your second expression concerns infinitely many events.  the first just concerns a single event.  I wouldn't expect the two expressions to be especially related.